# IN CQ, how to set value of all the items in Panel to blank

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem

In ExtJS `panel` I need to set value of all items (e.g. `textfield`, `pathfield`) to blank. I don't want to set value of each individual item to blank but of whole panel in one go.

I am able to get list of items

```
function getAllChildren (panel) {
   /*Get children of passed panel or an empty array if it doesn't have thems.*/
   var children = panel.items ? panel.items.items : [];

   /*For each child get their children and concatenate to result.*/
   CQ.Ext.each(children, function (child) {
      children = children.concat(getAllChildren(child));
   });

   return children;
}
```

but how to set to blank for whole panel? Please suggest what need to be done in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's not possible to do it with one liner - all at the same time. What your method returns is purely an array of objects. In fact if such syntax existed, it would iterate over all fields anyway.

Though clearing all fields, having the method you've proposed is very trivial to do. Just iterate over them all and call `reset` method. Mind some (especially custom) widgets might not handle it.

```
var fields = getAllChildren(panel);
CQ.Ext.each(fields, function(field) {
   if (child.reset) {
      child.reset();
   }
});
```

You've got similar loop in your `getAllChildren` code - you might reset field at the same place.

The method is defined in `Field` type which is usually a supertype of each dialog widget. You can read more [here](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html).